# Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on non-UEFI computer

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, uefi, live-usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 from a USB bootable disk and I'm getting this error:

```
ubuntu install error /casper/vmlinuz.efi read error @ 0
```

It's a non-UEFI BIOS, so I'm guessing the error is appearing because Ubuntu install is booting into UEFI mode, if so how to make it boot into legacy mode?

I tried renaming `vmlinuz.efi` to remove the `.efi` extension as I've seen some others do and that did nothing.

The error pops up twice, once before the language selection menu and again when I try to select an option like **Try Ubuntu** or **install Ubuntu**.

Comment: If your computer is not UEFI-compatible it is definitive impossible to boot anything in UEFI-mode. The error-message indicates that your disk/USB-stick is not ok. Beside the install-options there is an option "check disk for errors" . Choose this option and then hit Esc-key immediatly to see the output of the check on screen.

Answer (score 1):

I have just got Ubuntu working on my computer. Try creating the live USB using [UNetBootIn](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
to create the LiveUSB as suggested [here on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1653372).

That worked for me.

Comment: sites can be down any time it would be better if you post the step here

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me. I have a Lenovo z570 with no UEFI. After creating bootable Linux USB (via unetbootin/other software). just delete the EFI folder from the USB. Boot and install.

In my case for some reason, Ubuntu was attempting to install EFI in legacy mode, resulting in boot failure after installation. Removing the EFI folder from the installation medium skips EFI configured grub.