# /casper/vmlinuz.efi: not found for ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi, iso

> /casper/vmlinuz.efi: not found

is the error that is shown when i tried to start ubuntu for using vmware by downloading an `.iso` file for Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. What should I do now ?

Also , when I searched for the vmlinuz file, I did find it on my computer . However, there was no folder such as casper. Instead , it was under the directory : `C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu 64-bit\boot\isolinux`

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to boot. Is it a DVD created from the `.iso` file? Is it a USB flash drive? If the latter, how did you create it? If it's a DVD, chances are it's a bad burn. If it's a USB drive, chances are the program you used did it wrong, so you must either adjust its settings or use another program.

Comment: @RodSmith, yes, it is a DVD

Comment: @Ron, please, do you have a solution?

Comment: The problem, without a solution, was reported also [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/257078/439867) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/471696/439867). . PS: how to communicate with UBUNTU-ISO developers? It is a bug.

Comment: @PeterKrauss on my usual ubuntu installation is not `/casper/vmlinuz.efi` , too. btw I am on an old machine (Pentium IV).

Comment: @PeterKrauss What is the exact problem here? The original question reads like a problem with VMware, being unable to understand how booting works and where the file is located on the ISO. I could say I never had a problem with 14.04 and Live Media in both boot modes (in VirtualBox or actual hardware) that I couldn't fix and downloading VMware will take a while(...). So in what environment does your problem exist that you want to see fixed? A machine from 2006 could as well be a EFI Mac.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Hi, the problem is the bug at [iso of UBUNTU 14 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04.3&architecture=amd64). The bug is perceived only with old machines (~2006)... Is, perhaps only a wrong filename at iso.

Comment: @PeterKrauss I don't think it's a bug but a user error. In case you need to file a bug please use Launchpad. Bugs are off-topic here and I don't think putting a bounty on a poorly phrased user error question that only looks similar to your error message is going to solve your problem, you should rather open a new question with a detailed description so that someone else can reproduce and help (that's what I wanted from you in my last comment, not repeating the same non-descriptive statement as in the bounty).

Comment: @LiveWireBT hum... I think it is not is an "use error"... I checked, is a problem only arrives in UBUNTU install with old hardware with NVIDIA ... Is a bug because [need change ISO](http://askubuntu.com/a/265222/439867)...  see also [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1134770)

Answer (score 1):

1. create new Virtual Drive.
2. Loop that drive: losetup -f new_hard_disk_4_Vmware.vmdk
3. dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/loop(x)
4. losetup -d... or better still, gnome-disks -> detach with the button.
5. Mount new VMDK as drive 2

That or loop the ISO into fuse, and ride it as mounted by the os.
as a CD-Rom

Comment: Sorry, I abandoned the old machine after **so much problems with a supposed "plug and play" UBUNTU installation**... So, can not to test your solution. For any other reader: I perhaps will send the bounty to this solution, but I not  tested. (after change machine...) the simplest workaround (I used with success) is to insist: repeat and repeat install and the bug will be ignored

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the original question, I just checked and the issue is not reproducible with 14.04.3 ISO and VMware workstation.

Please follow [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328/40581) and consult the manual of your virtualization solution or your machine.

A little more detail: Your machine found one of the bootloaders on the media (El Torito MBR or EFI, EFI default loader in EFI\BOOT), but was unable to find the kernel to proceed. This is usually a user error in creating or using installation media, though with VMs there usually is not much to screw up: configure the machine, mount the image and install. If in doubt, try another distribution like Fedora, another boot method or other media. Also, while the kernel is named vmlinuz.efi, this doesn't imply EFI booting or any failure in doing so, it's apparently just a filename extension chosen to hint at that this kernel also includes an EFI stub but could boot both legacy and EFI. Furthermore since it's looking for a file that actually exists there is nothing that requires renaming, modifying or adding in the ISO.

(Yes this does not solve the problem brought up in the bounty, which has nothing to do with initial question, is even worse to reproduce and should be asked in a separate question if there exists no satisfying answer. Though IIRC how to modify an ISO with genisoimage has already been asked, my bookmarks just don't seem to have it any more. There apparently is no bug in the kernel and AU is not a bug tracker. Also I'm no more interested in the bounty, because there is no useful information to work with.)